# XPath expression not resulting in same result

Tags: parsing, xpath

I parse a website with a xpath-parser in Swift. The site has multiple pages with the same layout.

[The website.](https://bildungssystem.educa.ch/de/schools_in_ch?page=2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C15&title=&field_eduinst_canton_value=All&field_eduinst_type_value=All&field_eduinst_school_grade_value=All&ahah_page_storage[page_build_id]=page-72cd2d0cc7ac814bba6bbfb0b0bc0a3e)

The xpath is like that:

```
//div[@class='views-row views-row-4 views-row-even']/div[@class='details']/div[@class='detailscontainer']//tr[7]/td[2]
```

It works for almost every element on every page but suddenly, the xpath doesn't return the value it should.

I've checked the xpath with a extension in chrome and it is correct. But the parser doesn't find it.

For example on [this page](https://bildungssystem.educa.ch/de/schools_in_ch?page=2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C15&title=&field_eduinst_canton_value=All&field_eduinst_type_value=All&field_eduinst_school_grade_value=All&ahah_page_storage[page_build_id]=page-72cd2d0cc7ac814bba6bbfb0b0bc0a3e) it's the 'Gymnasium Laufen' where the 'Typ' row doesn't(tr[7]/td[2](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna)) return any values(null-crash) but it should, because it's the same as for the other records.

Suspicious is also, that some rows before are working. Like for example the first 4. But higher rows often don't work.

I'm using [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) as a parser. Here's my code:

```
for site in 15...49{


        var url = "https://bildungssystem.educa.ch/de/schools_in_ch?page=2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C" + site.description + "&title=&field_eduinst_canton_value=All&field_eduinst_type_value=All&field_eduinst_school_grade_value=All&ahah_page_storage[page_build_id]=page-72cd2d0cc7ac814bba6bbfb0b0bc0a3e"
        var urlRequest = NSURL(string: url)

        var error:NSError?

        let html = String(contentsOfURL: urlRequest!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

        if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            println(doc.title)

            for school in 1...25{
                if school == 22 && site == 49{
                    break
                }

                for td in 1...7{
                   println(doc.xpath("//div[@class='view-content']/div[starts-with(@class, 'views-row views-row-" + school.description + "')]/div[@class='details']/div[@class='detailscontainer']//tr[" + td.description + "]/td[2]")[0].text)
                }

            }
            println("SITE \(site) DONE")
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The content you're trying to query may be getting loaded dynamically (via JavaScript), and thus isn't available when the HTML initially renders. The reason why the Chrome extension works may be because Chrome is executing the JavaScript required to build out the DOM. However, when you use Kanna and a NSURLSession for example, their is no JavaScript engine being used to evaluate the JS.